# Is MySQL included in Azure Web-Apps?

Tags: azure, hosting, azure-web-apps

I am trying to find a cloud hosting solution for my simple web form + MySQL database, to make it possible for our employees to enter their shift details from multiple locations (Only like 10 people are going to use this form).

I thought Azure Web-Apps, with their cheapest plan should suffice for something small like this, but I am unsure if a MySQL db is already included, since I found a 2017 article saying they have a so called MySQL-in-App feature, but i can't find anything about it on the web-apps page, or if I will need to rent a seperate db for this.

Aditionnaly, if you, with your experience, want to tell me not to use Azure or something like this I would be glad to hear about your opinions. (I know opinion based questions are not liked here, so it's fine if you don't want to answer this question)

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, MySQL is not included when creating a Web App so you need to use the Azure Database for MySQL service.  However, when creating your Web App, search for "Web App + MySQL" and select "MySQL in App" as your Database provider.

Keep this in mind: "MySQL In App runs a local MySQL instance with your app and shares resources from the App Service plan. Note that apps using MySQL In App are not intended for production environments, and they will not scale beyond a single instance."

Here's the [product announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/18/announcing-mysql-in-app-preview-for-web-apps/) from the App Service team blog.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Even though they say it’s not really meant for production, this one instance should be enough for the workload I described right?

Comment: I'd say yes but you'll have to do some tests.  You can start with a small instance and move to a larger if needed.